# MPI Program Shutdown Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, perfect-numbers

Im using the ff:

- old dual core laptop
- Ubuntu 14.04
- openmpi

  ```
  int main() {

  int n = 34000000;
  int count = 0;

  MPI::Init();
  int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
  int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

  for(int i=rank+2; i<=n; i+= size) {
      if (isPerfect(i)) {
          count++;
      }
  }

  if (rank == 0) {
      for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
          MPI::Status status;
          MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&n, 1, MPI::INT, MPI::ANY_SOURCE, 0, status);
          count += n;
      }
      cout << count << " perfect #s" << n;
  } else {
      MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&count, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 0);
  }


  MPI::Finalize();

  return 0;
  ```

  }

  ```
  #include<math.h>

  bool isDivisible(int n, int d) {
      return n % d == 0;
  }


  bool isPerfect(int x) {
      int sum = 1;
      int max = ceil(sqrt(x));

      for(int i=2; i<max; i++) {
          if (isDivisible(x, i))
              sum += i + (x/i);

          if (max*max == x)
              sum += x;
      }

      return sum == x;
  }
  ```

I run the program using mpirun. `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`
A large value of `n` will make the 2 CPU 100% busy and after few minutes my laptop get shutdown.

Is there a problem in my program w/c causes the shutdown? How to get an idea for the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any problem i test it my self. maybe your laptop get shutdown because of overheat.